r barchart postion labels determined by y variable
I am creating a sparkline-ish R barchart.  My code so far is below:
plot1<-ggplot(data=puck98 %>% 
  mutate(win_loss = ifelse(wnls < 0, "loss", "win")), 
  aes(x=game, y=wnls, fill = win_loss)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.5)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green")) +
  geom_col() +
  ylim(-5,5) +
  geom_text(aes(label = status), vjust = 1) 
plot1

The green labels are OK just inside of the top of the bar but I want to get the red labels inside the bottom of the bar.  (Note not all bars should have labels.) I assume this involves an if statement on y variable wnls (coded 1 or -1) and changes to vjust but various combinations failed.  How to do so?
Thanks, RB

It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

Data is here: # A tibble: 9 × 3
game  wnls status
  
1     1     1 NA
2     2     1 NA
3     3    -1 NA
4     4     1 ot
5     5    -1 NA
6     6     1 so
7     7    -1 ot
8     8     1 NA
9     9    -1 so

Above not displaying well. Values: game (1..k), wnls (1, -1), status (so, ot, NA).

As you already guessed you can use an ifelse to conditionally set vjust to 0 or 1 inside aes() depending on the value of wnls:
Note: I switched to geom_label as it allows for some padding around the label.
set.seed(123)

n <- 20
puck98 <- data.frame(
  game = seq(n),
  wnls = sample(c(-1, 1), n, replace = TRUE),
  status = sample(c("so", "ot", NA), n, replace = TRUE)
)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

ggplot(
  data = puck98 %>%
    mutate(win_loss = ifelse(wnls < 0, "loss", "win")),
  aes(x = game, y = wnls, fill = win_loss)
) +
  geom_col(width = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green")) +
  geom_col() +
  ylim(-5, 5) +
  geom_label(
    aes(
      label = status,
      vjust = ifelse(wnls < 0, 0, 1)
    ),
    fill = NA, label.size = 0
  )
#> Warning: Removed 7 rows containing missing values or values outside the scale range
#> (`geom_label()`).



Perfect.  Thank you Stefan.  RB
